Tornado Server not able to take more then 10 Requests/sec
I currently have a Tornado RestAPI Server, it's an Async Server[using Async Handlers Methods].

This server needs to make multiple 3rd Party API Call for which i use
tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient with MaxClients as 100. AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, max_clients=100)
I use AsyncSession of SQLAlchemy to make Async DB Calls with a generator method to get session and handle the commit centrally along with some other handling.
@asynccontextmanager
async def session_scope():
   async with async_session() as session:
       yield session
       await session.commit()```





What's happening:
Currently as the server gets higher traffic what's observed through newrellic is the Python time increases and we start getting 502s. What seems to be the happening after like 8-10 Requests/Sec is that python starts waiting for existing requests and doesn't take new requests.
Note: This generally happens when the API calls of such APIs increases that have 3rd pary API Call taking 1-3 seconds.

The other thing that's happening[Not part of the above problem]
When I Tried Overriding write method in my base handler to get central response logging, i started getting Bad Yield Request. This same thing happened when i tried overriding finish()
File "/opt/python_environments/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 278, in _read_message
    delegate.finish()
File "/opt/python_environments/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 399, in finish

It seems its not affecting API Response but not sure.

What I'm Looking For

Is there any Buffer Limit or Other Limiter Setting I'm unaware about in tornado.
How do I properly profile the current code base to check if there is any gap as to closing DB or other connection as well as look into what all things are taking how much time.
Any Other way to get better insight into what's happening in the code.
The other Central Logging Issue I'm having while overriding write or finish. If there is any better way to do it. Or get more detail on this delegate and error as I'm not able to recognise any pattern or how to reproduce it as it only happens on prod and the logs don't give much[profiler might help here]


Tornado: 6.4.1
SQLAlchemy: 2.0.9
